# Microsoft Modern Authentication using Chrome with MSAL

Tags: google-chrome, azure-ad-msal

We are using MSAL library for Android version 2.0.1 as part of Android application which presents the calendar meetings on Android device running Android 9.

The Android device runs Intune Company Portal and the device was Enrolled successfully. The device complies with the company security rules. The identity certificate is installed using "Enable Browser Access" option in Intune.

When using Edge we succeeded with the Microsoft Modern Authentication. However, when using Chrome (which is the default Browser in Android phones) then the Microsoft Modern Authentication fails which means that we get the screen below AFTER entering the user credentials in the company login portal. When using Edge, user is requested to choose the certificate from the Android identity certificate store (after entering user credentials in company login portal). When using Chrome, user is NOT requested to choose the certificate from the Android identity certificate store and we get the screen below (implying the device is not enrolled while it is enrolled).
[image]

The link that the Android device uses with Edge and Chrome is below. With Edge it is working, but with Chrome not.

> `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oAuth2/v2.0/authorize?web_view_zoom_enabled=true&x-client-CPU=arm64-v8a&response_type=code&x-client-Ver=2.0.0&code_challenge_method=S256&x-client-DM=XYZ&x-client-OS=28&x-client-SKU=MSAL.Android&web_view_zoom_controls_enabled=true&client_id=...&client-request-id=...&instance_aware=false&scope=Calendars.Read%20User.Read%20openid%20offline_access%20profile&claims=%7B%7D&redirect_uri=...%3A%2F%2Fcallback&state=...&prompt=select_account&code_challenge=...`

However, if we use the link above, but remove the fields below then Microsoft Modern Authentication succeeded using Chrome.
`x-client-CPU=arm64-v8a`
`x-client-Ver=2.0.0`
`x-client-DM=XYZ`
`x-client-OS=28`
`x-client-SKU=MSAL.Android`

How this can be resolved?

Comment: Hi - Did you find a way to resolve this issue?

Comment: Sorry, but no. We opened https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-android/issues/1320 as well, but no comment.